# Can i install adb on Auto Linux BSP?

Tags: android, linux, bsp

I am working with a board that is connected to an android tablet. I need to program the connected android tablet to this board.

**Here is my set-up:**

- Operating System: Auto Linux BSP 1.0 (sumo)
- Kernel: Linux 4.19.59-rt24+g2db3cd3d11cf
- Architecture: arm64

**My Question:**

How can I install *adb* on a machine running Auto Linux BSP Os?
I know we can install adb on different linux platforms like below, but none of them work on Auto Linux BSP.

- Debian / Ubuntu

  sudo apt install android-tools-adb
- Centos / Fedora / openSUSE

  sudo dnf install android-tools
- ArchLinux and derivatives

  sudo pacman -Sy android-tools

Answer (score 0):

The only probable way I see is installing adb from sources.
Alternatively, you can try to cross-compile adb inside AOSP tree for arm64 architecture instead of desktop. This will require changing .bp - build config file for adb.